# Fill a jTextField with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a jTextField called fecha, by default, it has a text "dd/mm/aaaa" to show the user how to fill it, i've added an event for when it's clicked or has gained the focus it's text disappears. I want to use a shortcut as ctrl + A for filling the jTextField with the actual date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

To get today's date you can use this method:

```
    java.time.LocalDate.now()
```

You can use this to set the text inside the JTextField as today's date when 'Ctrl + A' gets pressed.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JTextField fecha = new JTextField(10);

            /* add a new action named "foo" to the panel's action map */
            fecha.getActionMap().put("foo", new AbstractAction() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        fecha.setText(java.time.LocalDate.now().toString());

                    }
                });


            InputMap inputMap = fecha.getInputMap();
            KeyStroke controlA =  KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control A");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Character.valueOf('a'), 0), "foo");
            inputMap.put(controlA, "foo");

            /* display the panel in a frame */
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(fecha);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll use another shortcut, thanks for answer. But do you know how to when having the focus already gained in fecha, use the shortcut to automatically fill the field?